# Building GLEW with MSYS: X11 not found

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu, glew, msys

When trying to make GLEW with MSYS, I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from src/glew.c:37:0:
include/GL/glxew.h:97:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>

compilation terminated.
make: *** [tmp/mingw/default/shared/glew.o] Error 1
```

Why?

Comment: you are using cygwin? install X11 devel package.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this, @LiessJemai ?

Comment: No, just got back to VS.

Answer (score -1):

MSYS does not have X11. It's **M**inimal SYStem for a reason. You want [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Or if you want to keep things Win32 native without Cygwin, take a look at [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).